# Avoiding division by $0$ error in simultaneous equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose I wanted to find the values of $\theta$ for which $\cos(\theta)x - \sin(\theta)y =2$ $(1)$ and $\sin(\theta)x + \cos(\theta)y =1 (2)$ where solvable. I could start with  writing $b = \sin(\theta)$ and $a = \cos(\theta)$ then rearranging $(2)$ for $y = \frac{1-bx}{a}$ if $a \ne 0$ then we can put this into $(1)$ and multiplying by $a$ gives $(a^2 + b^2)x = 2a + b$,  noting $a^2+b^2=1$, we have $x=2a+b$ and $y= a - 2b$ where $a \ne 0$. Looking at $a=0$ case separately we have $y=-2$ from $(1)$ and $x=1$ from $(2)$, so we have shown that the equations work for any value of $\cos(\theta)$ and hence any $\theta$. Now if we be naughty and put $a=0$ into our expressions we derived from assuming $a \ne 0$, we arive at $x = 1$ and $y=-2$, which we know to be correct. Now my question to you is, is this by chance? That the equations for $a \ne 0$ work for $a =0$? Or something more? Once we know that the equations work for $a=0$ can we "extend" their domain or something and allow for that case? Or must we always stick to the working with $a=0$ and $a \ne 0$ seperately?

Comment: The determinant of the system is $a^2+b^2=1 \neq 0$, hence the solution exists for all $\theta$. Performing a division while looking for the solution is ok, but you have be careful not to divide by zero. If the solution is the same, it means that it could have be found without using division.

Comment: Read about [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule). In particular, it gives you explicit formulae for a unique solution of a square system of linear equations of any order, provided that the determinant of the system is nonzero. (And, as others have pointed out, it is $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1\ne 0$.)

Comment: I will take a look at that, I am not sure about $det$ and matrices yet as I haven't started linear algebra in school yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have $a^2+b^2=1$ - multiplying the first equation by $a$ and the second by $b$ and adding gives $x=2a+b$ straight off.

Multiplying the first by $-b$ and the second by $a$ and adding gives $y=-2b+a$.

This involves no division by zero, and putting $a=0, b=\pm 1$ gives the two solutions for $a=0$ without a problem.

In such cases "multiply rather than divide" can avoid such errors easily, and also (in cases where it is important) isolates the issues with zero to the point where you have to divide.

Comment: Alright, but the equations I made are not allowed for $a=0$ right? I was right to check that case separately? Its only after we check them separately that we can deduce that because they work for $a=0$ too that a method to get the solution without division exists?

Comment: It is, however, harder to argue that the system of equations obtained by those operations is _equivalent_ to the original system. (Surely the only straightforward conclusion is that what you got is a _consequence_ of the original system.) This is easy to work around when the set of solutions is finite: just try them out in the original system.

Comment: Yes I agree, thanks!